# Show a percentage indicator while fetching data from Rest API Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am calling multiple API calls at the start of application and I want to show a percentage indicator to notify the user about the progress of data fetching.

I did find some plugins like `percent_indicator`, But I don't know how to calculate the percentage of task which is being done.

Anyone help me please with this issue.

Thankx

Comment: what i know long bytesDownloaded and long totalBytes need first, then we can calculation. i have ever on android native only, but in flutter i never though to implement because i am new. i think its only available on download progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to treat all calls equal, so the formula would be:

```
n / totalNumberCalls x 100 %
```

To get a more accurate result try to set weight to each call. This is naturally more experimental.

Comment: what is "n" in above formula.